# Optaplanner - Constraint streams groupBy

Tags: constraints, scheduling, optaplanner

I am trying to solve a scheduling problem, which centers around the following arrangement:

`Equipment` <- `Task` <- `ShiftAssignment`(Planning Variable) -> `Shift`

`Task`s have a problem fact of their equipment usage; each may reference a specific `Equipment` instance or instances, with an associated time in minutes. It takes up that time for that equipment in the `Shift` it's assigned to.

Should I be able to achieve the constraint with `join()` and `groupBy()`? I've tried pursuing the following route:

```
    private Constraint doNotOverbookEquipment(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.from(ShiftAssignment.class)
                // join shift assignments with the shifts they are assignments of
                .join(Shift.class, equal(ShiftAssignment::getShiftId, Shift::getId))
                // join with ALL pieces of equipment
                .join(Equipment.class)
                .groupBy([Shift and Equipment, summing the equipment-usage for each ShiftAssignment])
                .filter([equipment usage greater than a constant])
                .penalizeConfigurable("do not overbook Equipment");
```

I think the `filter()` should be no problem, but unsure exactly how to get this `groupBy()` to achieve what I want. Do I need a `TriConstraintCollector` here? Or is there a different, better overall approach?

For reference, the ShiftAssignment class can easily have a method like the following:

```
public LinkedHashSet<Equipment, Integer> getEquipmentUsage()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your `groupBy()` would look something like this:

```
.groupBy(
    (shiftAssignment, shift, equipment) -> shift,
    (shiftAssignment, shift, equipment) -> equipment,
    ConstraintCollectors.sum((shiftAssignment, shift, equipment) ->
        shiftAssignment.getUsage(shift, equipment)
)
```

The actual logic of what is to be summed should, in this case, be implemented in `shiftAssignment.getUsage(...)` or any other method you choose to use there.

Comment: Thanks for response. To clarify, I'm trying to end up with each 'row' being comprised of (Shift, Equipment, [sum over ShiftAssignments for usage of Equipment in Shift]).
If I'm not wrong, I think your proposed groupBy would result in (ShiftAssignment, sum(...)).

Comment: OK, took another shot at the answer. This will give a different sum for every unique pair of (Shift, Equipment).

Comment: How do you do same thing for ConstraintCollectors.min()?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying `min()` doesn't work? Feel free to ask another question.